# Why we need contract in kotlin scope function

Tags: android, kotlin

```kotlin
contract {
    callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
}
```

I have seen this in every single scope function in `Standard.kt` before they execute `block`, but when I tracked the definition of `contract` in `ContractBuilder.kt`, I find that it is a empty function, so why we need contract in kotlin scope function?

Comment: It is for handshaking with the compiler to tell it will only going to execute once. As a result `val a: String; scopingFunction { a = ... }; a` because the lambda will be called exactly once, a won't be able to reassigned so assignment to `val` is valid, and will be set and usable after it.

Comment: Thank you so much, as its name is a `contract` with the compiler to tell it the `block` is guaranteed to be executed only once.